# Does the iFruit app provide any advantages?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In the game, and the manual, players are informed that installing the [iFruit app](http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/51371/the-free-gtav-ifruit-and-game-manual-companion-apps.html) will allow for training Chop, and give the ability to customise vehicles.

While vehicle customisation is useful, it's nothing that can't, so far as I can tell as yet, be done in-game. Training Chop, however, is supposed to increase his in-game use to the player character(s). So: in the absence of an app at this time, does a player on iOS gain an advantage over those of us using Android?

Comment: Not really an answer, just commentary, but I've yet to find any real use for Chop. He is involved in one mission, but his happiness (or lack thereof) didn't seem to affect his performance in that mission. You also won't get customized plates which are only made in the app itself.

Comment: Chop is supposed to be useful in finding *Spaceship Parts* or *Paper Scraps*, but considering the *Rockstar Social Club* provides a map detailing the location of those, as well as whether you found them already or not, I'd say Chop's use is pretty much close to nil.

Answer (score 2):

Well, people with iFruit doesn't get an advantage, but they get a few more features.

When "taking care of Chop" on the app, you can teach him tricks, which you can get Chop to perform in-game. You can also get him another collar.

So the only thing android users are missing out on are a few small features.

Comment: You can customize your car to in LS Customs while away form your console. Hope they'll add online features like BAWSAQ so we could get money while offline :D

Comment: @Warface Yes, they'll most likely add BAWSAQ in a future update! I mean, they have officially announced an online stock market.